# How to remove any non-Persian character in a string in python?

Tags: python

I want to remove any non-Persian character in a string in python.
For example if I have a string like this:

```
00سلامabc
```

I have the Persian characters and the result becomes like this:

```
سلام
```

I know that it is possible that I can extract just Persian characters from a string by regex.
But I have four questions:

1. Which type of characters should I consider? ascii or unicode?
2. Is there Persian range in ascii or unicode?
3. Which language should I use? Arabic or Persian?
4. How do I find the range of the alphabets?

Comment: I recommend typing your question title to google and finding the regex in 3rd or 4th option

Comment: I recommend you look at how Unicode works, given how many questions you have. Stack overflow is not a tutorial site. Check out the python howto instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to find all the persian characters and join them back together...

```
import re

def persian_only(s):
    return "".join(re.findall(r"[\u0600-\u06FF]+", s))

>>> persian_only("00سلامabc")
سلام
```

https://trinket.io/python3/cc31b7b436

Comment: The answer is great and works well. But what characters does your range cover? does this cover Arabic characters? You know there is a problem in Persian language that some characters has some different style of writings.

Comment: @HosseinSedghian It is the arabic unicode character block - https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/arabic/list.htm

Comment: Alternatively, import regex instead of re, and use the pattern r'\p{Arabic}+' to match the Arabic script characters, or r'\P{Arabic}+' to match all non-Arabic characters.

Alternatively, if you what to keep the data, but not have Arabic characters in there, do a text transform to transcribe or transliterate Arabic to Latin.